# How to print the random answer from the given answer in python

Tags: python

I want to get different result every time(or most of the time) by using or(|) condition in python, however nothing worked for me.

(1). if given_input == 'b':

```
    print(" You Pressed b " or " B is pressed")
```

(2). if given_input == 'b':

```
    print(" You Pressed b ")  or print(" B is pressed")
```

(3). if given_input == 'b':

```
    print(" You Pressed b " | " B is pressed") ​
```

(4). if given_input == 'b':

```
    ​print(" You Pressed b ")  | print(" B is pressed")
```

Comment: 1) Form a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) or list with your items; 2) Use [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) to select one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither `or` nor `|` (binary or) can't do what you want to do.
You need to `import random` and then use `random.choice(["You pressed b", "B is pressed"])`